# NestJS gRPC Cant connect to microservice

Tags: node.js, microservices, nestjs, grpc, grpc-node

When i trying to call some method from service im getting "Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: No connection established"

Code in some module:

```
imports: [
    ClientsModule.register([
        {
            name: 'UsersService',
            transport: Transport.GRPC,
            options: {
                url: 'localhost:50051',
                package: 'users',
                protoPath: 'path/to/proto',
            }
        }
    ])
],
```

Users microservice:

```
async function bootstrap() {
    const app = await NestFactory.createMicroservice(
        UsersModule,
        {
            transport: Transport.GRPC,
            options: {
                url: 'localhost:50051',
                package: 'users',
                protoPath: 'path/to/proto',
            }
        },
    )
}
```

Full error

```
[Nest] 3644  - 12.06.2022, 22:11:54   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] 14 UNAVAILABLE: No connection established
Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: No connection established
    at Object.callErrorFromStatus (C:\Users\123\Desktop\projects\syntx\api-gateway\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\src\call.ts:81:24)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (C:\Users\123\Desktop\projects\syntx\api-gateway\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\src\client.ts:351:36)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (C:\Users\123\Desktop\projects\syntx\api-gateway\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\src\client-interceptors.ts:462:34)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (C:\Users\123\Desktop\projects\syntx\api-gateway\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\src\client-interceptors.ts:424:48)
    at C:\Users\123\Desktop\projects\syntx\api-gateway\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\src\call-stream.ts:330:24
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What happened? Did you find any solution?

Comment: @FabioZapata I solved the issue but I forgot what was the problem. Code in microservices has not been changed

Comment: Yeah, I have a similar issue using k8s and the problem was calling localhost:50051, we needed to move to 0.0.0.0:50051